# Site Collection Migration to correct content database

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

We are migrating from 2010 to 2013 environment and having issues with one part of our migration. We have a web app that has site collections pointing to 2 different databases. I mounted the first database and was able to get the sites created and pointed properly. I am unsure how to mount and point the remaining sites to the next database.

has anyone ran into this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Their should be not a problem.I migrated many web apps with multiple databases.You should repeat the Database move steps mount steps.

As you already moved the create the web app and moved the 1st DB.

- Perform the backup of DB on source server
- Move the files to destination server
- Restore the DB on Destination Server
- Mount the DB to destination's web app(same way you did).
- now you will see all the site collections(remaining)